# Using Azure Managed Library from WinRT

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Is it possible to use a Managed Library to access Azure from a WinRT component?

As I understand I cannot reference the Managed Library dll's in the WinRT/Metro profile.

I could use the REST API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179355) but would prefer a managed API.

Comment: In Windows what the name of the Library?

Comment: Its called Windows Azure Managed Library http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee393295 (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll and
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll)

Answer (score 2):

The current release (1.7) of these libraries cannot be called from within a metro app. For most of these it would not make a lot of sense to be callable from WinRT component anyway.

The link you reference essentially has three different sets of libraries -

- **Storage client libs** These are used to access Azure storage. These are essentially
  wrappers around the corresponding REST APIs.
- **ServiceRuntime libs** These are used to access your tenant/role/instance
  properties from within your    running tenant on Azure.
- **Diagnostics libs** These are to configure and write    logs from your running
  Azure app onto your Azure storage account.

It totally makes sense to have Storage client libs callable from metro apps, but the support is not there in 1.7. You would probably have to roll your own REST calls. You can get a good idea of how to write this code by looking at the corresponding Java code that MS has open sourced [here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java).

For the other two, your app using these libs will be running on a Windows Azure VM. As such you would not need to use them in a metro app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: -> "but the support is not there in 1.7". So you are saying that the REST API's is a newer version than the client lib's?

Comment: No, the client libraries simply wrap the REST APIs.  The REST APIs are actually the only way to talk to Azure storage, all the libraries you see simply wrap this functionality for your language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Certain classes in the Windows Azure managed library relies on desktop components which are not available in Metro. For example, table storage client relies on WCF Data Services. So you cannot use those assemblies in a Metro application. Please use the REST API, or create a hosted service in Windows Azure which performs all tasks related to Windows Azure, and let you Metro application communicate with your own service. The Windows Azure Toolkit for Windows 8 may also help: http://watwindows8.codeplex.com/.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Answer (score 0):

New version of Windows Azure Storage Client Library supports Windows Store apps. Please find more information at [Windows Azure Storage Client Library for Windows Runtime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/05/windows-azure-storage-client-library-for-windows-runtime.aspx).